# How to use the path generated in one shell script in another shell script?

Tags: shell, jenkins, robotframework

I've a Jenkins robot framework file that uses two shell scripts.

*Shell Script1*: It creates a tar ball of the test environment and stores it in a certain location/path.

*Shell script2*: It is to deploy the test environment created & stored in a certain location.

So to run the shell script2, I need to use the path of the test enviroment stored location created by script1.

I've created a variable like below in script1 and stored the path.

*export TARBALL_PATH="${DEST_FOLDER}/test_tar_ball*

The question is how to use the variable "TARBALL_PATH" in shell script2 to deploy the test env(created and stored in script1)?

In script2, tried to use the "TARBALL_PATH" variable created in script1 like below but it did not workout.

```
echo $TARBALL_PATH
WS_DIR=`TARBALL_PATH`
```

Can someone help me with the issue? My script uses *#!/bin/bash*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you modify script1 to print the value to stdout, and catch the output in a Jenkins variable? Another possibility would be to have script1 write this value to a file and read the file in script2. Or is it really necessary that script1 decides on its own, how the tarball is named? Maybe you can define a file path for it inside your Jenkins task and pass that name to script1 and script2.

Comment: The script1 generates a softlink like below where the tar ball resides

 ln -sfn build-1.0.135-test-20230629-133144/src /jenkins/air-default/workspace/N_basic_development_test_develop/reports/Dev-test

and I need to access this path "/jenkins/air-default/workspace/N_basic_development_test_develop/reports/Dev-test"

Comment: I didn't say that the script shoiuldn't generate the link. But can't you pass the path for the softlink to be generated from Jenkins to the script?

Comment: No, the way shell script1 is already implemented to generate the soft link by itself and now, the thing is make use of that path in the other shell script2.

Comment: So, if you don't want  / can't change this aspect of the implementation, how then using one of my other suggestions? I think your problem boils down to "how can a program use information, which has been generated by a different program".